# Discord.MessageEmbed is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So recently I tried adding a command handler into my discord bot. All the commands that had Embeds came up with the error "Discord.MessageEmbed is not a constructor".

this only happened when i added the command handler but the commands worked fine without it.

further details:
discord.js version [12]
node version [14.15.3]

code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: "Sets up a dynamic help message!",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
        const purge = ':one:';
        const music = ':two:';
        const ban = ':three:';
    
        const purgeembed = new MessageEmbed()

                         

        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setTitle('purge info')
        .setDescription("this is a embed for more info about the purge command and how to use it")
        .addFields(
            {name: ' ‍ ', value: "`this command allows a user to purge (delete) messages that are less than 14 days old`", inline: true},
            {name: ' ‍ ', value: '%purge [number of messages < 1000]'}
        )
        .setFooter("check bellow for how it works  [unfinished]");


        const musicembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                            
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setTitle('music info')
        .setDescription("this is a embed for more info about the music command and how to use it")
        .addFields(
            {name: ' ‍ ', value: "`this command allows a user to listen to music in a voice channel with alot of options like playing music from a link or by searching for the song through yt there is also a Queuing for music`", inline: true},
            {name: ' ‍ ', value: "`assoiciated commands:`",},
            {name: ' ‍ ', value: "`......`", inline: true},
            {name: ' ‍ ', value: "`......`", inline: true},
            {name: ' ‍ ', value: "`......`", inline: true},
            {name: ' ‍ ', value: "`......`", inline: true},
            {name: ' ‍ ', value: "`......`", inline: true},
            {name: ' ‍ ', value: "`%...`"},
        )
        .setFooter("check bellow for how it works  [unfinished]"); 
        



        const banembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                            
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setTitle('ban info')
        .setDescription("this is a embed for more info about the ban command and how to use it")
        .addFields(
            {name: ' ‍ ', value: "`this command allows a moderator to ban a user`", inline: true},
            {name: ' ‍ ', value: "`you can ban a user if you are a moderator but you need to give a reason to the owner first`"},
            {name: ' ‍ ', value: "`%ban @user`"},
        )
        .setFooter("check bellow for how it works  [unfinished]");


 
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setTitle('Choose a reaction for more info about a command!')
            .setDescription('Choosing a reaction will allow you to get more info about a specific command!\n\n'
                + `${purge} for purge help\n\n`
                + `${music} for music help\n\n`
                + `${ban} for ban help\n\n`);
 
                message.channel.send(embed).then(embedMessage => {
                    embedMessage.react('1️⃣');
                    embedMessage.react('2️⃣');
                    embedMessage.react('3️⃣');
                  });

           
                  message.client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
                   
                  if (user.id === '795613081295650837'){

                   }else{
                    
                    

                      if (reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣') {
                        
                        message.channel.bulkDelete(1);

                      setTimeout(function(){ 
                                    message.channel.send(purgeembed);
                                }, 600);
                                        
                        }
                        if (reaction.emoji.name === '2️⃣') {

                            message.channel.bulkDelete(1);

                          setTimeout(function(){ 
                                    message.channel.send(musicembed);
                                }, 600);
                        }
                        if (reaction.emoji.name === '3️⃣') {

                            message.channel.bulkDelete(1);

                          setTimeout(function(){ 
                                    message.channel.send(banembed);
                                }, 600);
                            }
                     else {
                        return;
                    }}
 
        });
    }
 
}
```

full error:

```
(node:15924) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Discord.MessageEmbed is not a constructor
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\x\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\commands\help.js:25:28)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\x\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\events\guild\message.js:9:24)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\x\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\x\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\x\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\x\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\x\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\x\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:15924) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15924) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
C:\Users\x\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\events\client\ready.js:9
              Client.user.setPresence({
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPresence' of undefined
    at Timeout.presence [as _onTimeout] (C:\Users\x\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\events\client\ready.js:9:27)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

main file:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"]});
const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler =>{
   require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
})




/* const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of commandFiles){

   const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
   client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
   function presence() {
      let status = ['<help for help'] //you can add how many you like
      let rstatus = Math.floor(Math.random() * status.length); //this chooses a status from the ones you typed up
      client.user.setPresence({
          status: "online", //you can change to offline, dnd
          type: "WATCHING",
          activity: {
              name: `${status[rstatus]}`, //rhese sets the status                type: "WATCHING" //you can change to listening, streaming, playing (just a quick google search :) )
          }
      });
  }
  console.log(`Discord Bot ${client.user.tag} is online!`); // the presence needs to be like this, near the ready event
  setInterval(presence, 30000) //you can reduce/add the time (milliseconds) if you reduce it l3ss then 15 seconds your bot will get ratelimited
});

client.on('message', message =>{

   if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;  
   const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
   const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
   message.delete();

   if(command === 'help'){
   client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args, Discord);
   }else if(command == 'purge'){
   client.commands.get('purge').execute(message, args, Discord);
   }else if(command == 'play'){
      client.commands.get('play').execute(message, args, Discord);
   }else if(command == 'congrat'){
      client.commands.get('congrat').execute(message, args, Discord);
   }else if(command == 'kick'){
      client.commands.get('kick').execut(emessage, args, Discord);
   }else if(command == 'ban'){
      client.commands.get('ban').execute(message, args, Discord);
   }else if(command == 'ping'){
      client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args, Discord);
   }
}); */

client.login('token')
```

any help would be highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

*Update:* If you're using v14 and receive the error above, it's because `MessageEmbed` is now `EmbedBuilder`. For more info, you can check out this answer: [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14).

It seems you're (not) passing down a `Discord` variable to your `execute` method and mix `new Discord.MessageEmbed()` and `new MessageEmbed()` (the one you're `require`ing from `discord-js`). Try to replace all `new Discord.MessageEmbed()` with `newMessageEmbed()` and it should work.

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'help',
  description: 'Sets up a dynamic help message!',
  async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
    const purge = ':one:';
    const music = ':two:';
    const ban = ':three:';

    const purgeembed = new MessageEmbed()

      .setColor('RANDOM')
      .setTitle('purge info')
      .setDescription(
        'this is a embed for more info about the purge command and how to use it',
      )
      .addFields(
        {
          name: ' ‍ ',
          value:
            '`this command allows a user to purge (delete) messages that are less than 14 days old`',
          inline: true,
        },
        { name: ' ‍ ', value: '%purge [number of messages < 1000]' },
      )
      .setFooter('check bellow for how it works  [unfinished]');

    const musicembed = new MessageEmbed()

      .setColor('RANDOM')
      .setTitle('music info')
      .setDescription(
        'this is a embed for more info about the music command and how to use it',
      )
      .addFields(
        {
          name: ' ‍ ',
          value:
            '`this command allows a user to listen to music in a voice channel with alot of options like playing music from a link or by searching for the song through yt there is also a Queuing for music`',
          inline: true,
        },
        { name: ' ‍ ', value: '`assoiciated commands:`' },
        { name: ' ‍ ', value: '`......`', inline: true },
        { name: ' ‍ ', value: '`......`', inline: true },
        { name: ' ‍ ', value: '`......`', inline: true },
        { name: ' ‍ ', value: '`......`', inline: true },
        { name: ' ‍ ', value: '`......`', inline: true },
        { name: ' ‍ ', value: '`%...`' },
      )
      .setFooter('check bellow for how it works  [unfinished]');

    const banembed = new MessageEmbed()

      .setColor('RANDOM')
      .setTitle('ban info')
      .setDescription(
        'this is a embed for more info about the ban command and how to use it',
      )
      .addFields(
        {
          name: ' ‍ ',
          value: '`this command allows a moderator to ban a user`',
          inline: true,
        },
        {
          name: ' ‍ ',
          value:
            '`you can ban a user if you are a moderator but you need to give a reason to the owner first`',
        },
        { name: ' ‍ ', value: '`%ban @user`' },
      )
      .setFooter('check bellow for how it works  [unfinished]');

    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('RANDOM')
      .setTitle('Choose a reaction for more info about a command!')
      .setDescription(
        'Choosing a reaction will allow you to get more info about a specific command!\n\n' +
          `${purge} for purge help\n\n` +
          `${music} for music help\n\n` +
          `${ban} for ban help\n\n`,
      );

    message.channel.send(embed).then((embedMessage) => {
      embedMessage.react('1️⃣');
      embedMessage.react('2️⃣');
      embedMessage.react('3️⃣');
    });

    message.client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
      if (user.id === '795613081295650837') {
      } else {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣') {
          message.channel.bulkDelete(1);

          setTimeout(function () {
            message.channel.send(purgeembed);
          }, 600);
        }
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '2️⃣') {
          message.channel.bulkDelete(1);

          setTimeout(function () {
            message.channel.send(musicembed);
          }, 600);
        }
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '3️⃣') {
          message.channel.bulkDelete(1);

          setTimeout(function () {
            message.channel.send(banembed);
          }, 600);
        } else {
          return;
        }
      }
    });
  },
};
```

Other option is to check how you call the `execute` method in the main file. If you pass `Discord` as the third argument, you don't need to use `const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');` on top and only use `new Discord.MessageEmbed()`s everywhere.

Comment: hi @Zsolt Meszaros i did exactly what u said and now i get another error:
`(node:1604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: MessageEmbed is not defined`

Comment: You don't need to delete `const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');` if you use `new MessageEmbed()`.

Comment: omg i highly appreciate your help but now im getting another error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

Comment: It seems there is some mess where you call `execute()` in your main file. Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66159562/edit) and add that part? It's something like `client.commands.get('help').execute(...`

Comment: ok i will edit it now and add my main file

Answer (score 1):

If anybody else landed here for the issue title:

```
Discord.MessageEmbed is not a constructor
```

`discord.js` changed the class from `MessageEmbed` to `EmbedBuilder` in version `14.0.1`.

I personally had to do the following changes

**OLD CODE**

```
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING,
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING
    ]
})
```

**NEW CODE**

```
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageReactions,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping
    ]
})
```

If you want to see the exact change look at the [git diff in my repository](https://github.com/Axelfoley85/discordjs-captain-hook/commit/412f163c73d2ef2f80f0b1896a5a62be2dcc432b?diff=split)

A full list of Intents can be found here [Discord developer portal: list-of-intents](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents)

If you have more issues related to version change to v14 check out [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73028855/8433161) as mentioned in the answer above.

Comment: Thank you, I had the same issue and this solution is it.