# Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've just updated my discord.js from v13 to v14 and there are many errors.

**Errors with `message` and `interaction` events:**

Neither `message` nor `interaction` events fire.

**Errors with intents:**

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
  ],
});
//     Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
//            ^
//
// TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')

const client = new Client({
  intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MEMBERS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES'],
});
//    throw new RangeError(ErrorCodes.BitFieldInvalid, bit);
//
// RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: GUILDS.
```

**Errors with `interaction`s:**

```js
if (interaction.isCommand()) {}
// TypeError: interaction.isCommand is not a function

if (interaction.isAutocomplete()) {}
// TypeError: interaction.isAutocomplete is not a function

if (interaction.isMessageComponent()) {}
// TypeError: interaction.isMessageComponent is not a function

if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {}
// TypeError: interaction.isModalSubmit is not a function
```

**Errors with channels:**

```js
if (message.channel.isText()) {}
// TypeError: channel.isText is not a function

if (message.channel.isVoice()) {}
// TypeError: channel.isVoice is not a function

if (message.channel.isDM()) {}
// TypeError: channel.isDM is not a function

if (message.channel.isCategory()) {}
// TypeError: channel.isCategory is not a function
```

**Errors with builders and embeds:**

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed();
//  const embed = new MessageEmbed();
//                ^
//
// TypeError: MessageEmbed is not a constructor

const button = new MessageButton();
//  const button = new MessageButton();
//                 ^
//
// TypeError: MessageButton is not a constructor

const actionRow = new MessageActionRow();
//  const actionRow = new MessageActionRow();
//                    ^
//
// TypeError: MessageActionRow is not a constructor

const selectMenu = new MessageSelectMenu();
//  const selectMenu = new MessageSelectMenu();
//                     ^
//
// TypeError: MessageSelectMenu is not a constructor

const textInput = new TextInputComponent();
//  const textInput = new TextInputComponent();
//                    ^
//
// TypeError: TextInputComponent is not a constructor

const modal = new Modal();
//  const modal = new Modal();
//                ^
//
// TypeError: Modal is not a constructor

const attachment = new MessageAttachment();
//  const attachment = new MessageAttachment();
//                     ^
//
// TypeError: MessageAttachment is not a constructor
```

**Errors with enums:**

```js
new ButtonBuilder()
  .setCustomId('verification')
  .setStyle('PRIMARY')

// UnknownEnumValueError: Expected the value to be one of the following enum values:
//     at NativeEnumValidator.handle

new TextInputBuilder()
  .setCustomId('verification')
  .setStyle('SHORT')

// UnknownEnumValueError: Expected the value to be one of the following enum values:
//     at NativeEnumValidator.handle
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Discord.js v14 includes many breaking changes. It now requires Node 16.9 or higher to use, so make sure you [upgrade to the latest LTS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075990/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version).

This version of v14 uses the [Discord API v10](https://discord.com/developers/docs/change-log#api-v10).

#### Errors with `message` and `interaction` events:

The `message` and `interaction` events are now removed. You can use the `messageCreate` and `interactionCreate` events instead.

```js
// v13
client.on('message', (message) => {
  console.log(` doesn't fire`);
});
client.on('interaction', (interaction) => {
  console.log(` doesn't fire`);
});

// v14
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  console.log(` works as expected`);
});
client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
  console.log(` works as expected`);
});
```

#### Errors with intents:

```js
// v13
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
  ],
});

// OR
const client = new Client({
  intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES'],
});

// v14
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
  ],
});
```

For a full list of `GatewayIntentBits`, you can [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027274/6126373).

#### Errors with `interaction`s:

Some interaction type guards have been removed. You can compare `interaction.type` against the [`InteractionType` enum](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/InteractionType) instead.

```js
const { InteractionType } = require('discord.js');

// v13
if (interaction.isCommand()) {}
// v14
if (interaction.type === InteractionType.ApplicationCommand) {}

// v13
if (interaction.isAutocomplete()) {}
// v14
if (interaction.type === InteractionType.ApplicationCommandAutocomplete) {}

// v13
if (interaction.isMessageComponent()) {}
// v14
if (interaction.type === InteractionType.MessageComponent) {}

// v13
if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {}
// v14
if (interaction.type === InteractionType.ModalSubmit) {}
```

#### Errors with channels:

Some channel type guards have been removed. To narrow channels, you can compare `channel.type` to a [`ChannelType` enum](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/ChannelType) instead.

```js
const { ChannelType } = require('discord.js');
// v13
if (message.channel.isText()) {}
// v14
if (channel.type === ChannelType.GuildText) {}

// v13
if (message.channel.isVoice()) {}
// v14
if (channel.type === ChannelType.GuildVoice) {}

// v13
if (message.channel.isDM()) {}
// v14
if (channel.type === ChannelType.DM) {}

// v13
if (message.channel.isCategory()) {}
// v14
if (channel.type === ChannelType.GuildCategory) {}
```

For a full list of `ChannelType`s, you can [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027955/6126373).

Also, there are some new type guards:

```js
channel.isDMBased();
channel.isTextBased();
channel.isVoiceBased();
```

#### Errors with builders and embeds:

`MessageEmbed` has been renamed to `EmbedBuilder`.

```js
// v13
const embed = new MessageEmbed();
// v14
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const embed = new EmbedBuilder();
```

`MessageAttachment` has been renamed to `AttachmentBuilder` and instead of taking the name as the second parameter, it accepts an [AttachmentData object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/AttachmentData).

```js
// v13
const attachment = new MessageAttachment(buffer, 'image.png');
// v14 
const { AttachmentBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const attachment = new AttachmentBuilder(buffer, { name: 'image.png' });
```

`MessageComponents` have been renamed; they no longer have the `Message` prefix and now have a `Builder` suffix.

```js
// v13
const button = new MessageButton();
// v14 
const { ButtonBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const button = new ButtonBuilder();

// v13
const actionRow = new MessageActionRow();
// v14 
const { ActionRowBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const actionRow = new ActionRowBuilder();

// v13
const selectMenu = new MessageSelectMenu();
// v14
const { SelectMenuBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const selectMenu = new SelectMenuBuilder();

// v13
const textInput = new TextInputComponent();
// v14
const { TextInputBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const textInput = new TextInputBuilder();
```

#### Errors with enums:

Any areas that used to accept a string or number type for an enum parameter will now only accept exclusively numbers.

```js
// Wrong
new ButtonBuilder()
  .setCustomId('verification')
  .setStyle('PRIMARY')

// Fixed
const { ButtonStyle } = require('discord.js');
new ButtonBuilder()
  .setCustomId('verification')
  .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)

// Wrong
new TextInputBuilder()
  .setCustomId('verification')
  .setStyle('SHORT')

// Fixed
const { TextInputStyle } = require('discord.js');
new TextInputBuilder()
  .setCustomId('verification')
  .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
```

Errors with activity types: [setPresence activity type in discord.js v14 can only be set to "PLAYING"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73049373/setpresence-activity-type-in-discord-js-v14-can-only-be-set-to-playing)

If `message.content` doesn't have any value, [add the GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent enum to your intents array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73037243/6126373)

For more breaking changes, you can visit the discord.js guide: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html

Comment: Another change that will bug people a lot is the fact that arguments that used to accept enums or strings, now only accept enums. I'd say this is important and probably should be added to the answer (and probably question)

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I've just added some. Not sure which ones are the most common though :)

Comment: I also saw something in the discord.js support server a lot, which however only applies to TypeScript. When making an action row in ts, `new ActionRowBuilder()` is not sufficient. You need `new ActionRowBuilder<ComponentType>()`. Example: `new ActionRowBuilder<ButtonBuilder>()`. This way you can only add `ButtonBuilder`s to components, and it won't allow you to send it to a modal (since buttons aren't allowed there)

Comment: About the typeguards for interactions, for some reason they still work for me, is that normal? I've double checked and I'm on v14.

Comment: The discord.js developers added them back, only for interactions. This was because of inconsistencies.

Comment: A full list of Intents can be found here [list-of-intents](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents)