# message.content doesn't have any value in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

With discord v14, I was trying to use the `messageCreate` event, however, after a user types a message in discord, `message.content` doesn't have any data as shown below:

```js
Message {
  channelId: '998889338475655188',
  guildId: '948995127148425246',
  id: '998925735668498433',
  createdTimestamp: 1658232854526,
  type: 0,
  system: false,
  content: '',
  author: User
```

I have tried searching around and can't find any solution to the issue, the code I am using relating to discord is:

```js
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } from "discord.js";

const bot = new Client({
  'intents': [
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
  ],
  'partials': [Partials.Channel]
});

bot.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  console.log(message);
});

bot.login(process.env.token1)
```

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong or what needs changing from the new update?

Comment: confirm you have the guild messages intent set and content/msg is not partial?

Comment: @0xLogN It will work if the message is sent from itself. For instance I did: ```bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`The Discord bot ${bot.user.username} is ready!`);
  bot.channels.cache.get(outputChannelID).send(`The Discord bot ${bot.user.username} is ready!`);
});```
And in the console.log from `'messageCreate' async (message)` I get `content: The Discord bot bot.user.username is ready!`  But not for users.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Make sure you enable the message content intent on your [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and add the `GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent` enum to your `intents` array.

Applications ↦ Settings ↦ Bot ↦ Privileged Gateway Intents

[image]

You'll also need to add the `MessageContent` intent:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
  partials: [Partials.Channel],
});
```

And make sure to use the `messageCreate` event instead of `message`:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {});
```

If you're using discord.js v13, you'll need to enable the message content intent on your developer portal and if your bot uses the Discord API v10, you will need to add the `MESSAGE_CONTENT` flag to your intents:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.MESSAGE_CONTENT,
  ],
});
```

Comment: Discordjs v14 migrading doesn't say to add GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent they forgot to add it or smth

Comment: @It'sMateo20 — It's a change in the permissions requirements at Discord's end. I assume discord.js has supported it for a while.

Comment: For anyone facing the same issue but in DMs. You should add `GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages` in the intents as explained above