# Discord bot not responding to "ping" command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been having trouble with my code for a simple ping command that gets the bot to reply to `!ping` I've copied so many different techniques from loads of different videos, websites etc. that "supposedly" work but when I type `!ping` my bot does nothing.

My bot is online but I feel there's something stupidly obvious I'm forgetting. I searched the web and I think there's something wrong with the intents. I looked at versions that both used `MessageCreate` and `Message`, too, and I'm not sure which is correct. I tried this tutorial as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTGtiCC3iQM&t=185s

Here is my code:

```
//constants
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { ActivityType } = require("discord.js");
const prefix = '!';
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('CARI is online');
    client.user.setActivity('paint dry.', { type: ActivityType.Watching });
}); 

client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
        msg.reply('pong');
    }
});

client.login('TOKEN');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [message.content doesn't have any value in Discord.js v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036854/message-content-doesnt-have-any-value-in-discord-js-v14)

Comment: sorry, not working still.

Comment: Can you update your question with details of what you have tried?

Comment: Done. Also included a link to the tutorial I was trying to follow if it helps.

Comment: Okay, that's an old tutorial. What I wanted to know is if you visited the dev portal, ticked the message content intent under Privileged Gateway Intents and added `GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent` too

Comment: Yes I just checked and I have.

Comment: Is there a `function(msg)` on v14? Try removing the `function`

Comment: Thanks. I changed it but my but still refuses to say anything.

Comment: @新Acesyyy, of course there is. It has nothing to do with Discord.js, it's just JavaScript. You can have normal functions as callbacks anywhere.

Comment: @Greencappuccino have you checked the value of `message.content`?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros THANK YOU SO MUCH NOW YOU POINTED IT OUT IT'S SO OBVIOUS! I MEANT !ping. Now I know It's working now. I knew It would be something obvious. Thanks SO much!

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros, OP used `msg.content` so I didnt think that using `prefix` will solve the problem, that's why i think the `function statement`

Comment: are you saying ping or !ping