# Why is my messageCreate event not working? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried making a discord bot..

I looked for some tutorials but my code doesn't seem to work..

I created a simple ping pong command but for some reason its not working!

Heres my bot.js code:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, 'GuildMessages'] });

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log(`Thunder bot is ready! Tag is ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.on('message', (messageCreate) => {
if (message.content === 'ping'){
    message.reply('Pong!')
}
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

But the ping pong command is not working!

Comment: Dont you need to use it like `messageCreate.content` and `messageCreate.reply` since you write `messageCreate` on `client.on` function?

Comment: In the `client.on('messageCreate')` event listener, you have named the message you get as `messageCreate`. Then you are trying to reply to a variable which doesn't exist which is `message`. So you just have to change that

Comment: Voted to close as it's typo: `client.on('message', (messageCreate)` should be `client.on('messageCreate', (message) =`. You'll also need [the `GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent` intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036854/message-content-doesnt-have-any-value-in-discord-js-v14/73037243#73037243).

Comment: @Batu.Khan I did that.. still not working!

Comment: @Caladan still not working

Comment: Instead of the `GuildMessages` intent in the client, use `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 reasons your bot isn't responding to you:

1. Your bot doesn't have 'MessageContent' intent

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: ['Guilds', 'GuildMessages', 'MessageContent'] });
```

2. `client.on('message'`... may result to a DeprecationWarning
   Here is the correction:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.content === 'ping'){
        message.reply('Pong!')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to use the following intents to read and react to messages:

```
{ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] }
```

2. The event you want to listen for is called "messageCreate" (you were listening for "message"):

```
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
if (message.content === 'ping'){
    message.reply('Pong!')
}
});
```

This should work:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log(`Thunder bot is ready! Tag is ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
if (message.content === 'ping'){
    console.log("!")
    message.reply('Pong!')
}
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Comment: Oh! I did a typo! Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

2 reasons this is happening;

1. You put `message` instead of `messageCreate` and vice versa in your `client.on()`. Put this instead:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (message.content === 'ping'){
        message.reply('Pong!')
    }
});
```

2. You're missing the messageContent intent.

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: ["Guilds", "GuildMessages", "MessageContent"] });
```