# Discord.js v14 client.on("messageCreate" doesn't work, what do I do?

Tags: discord.js

Before you ask: I have the correct intents `[Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds]`.

Here's what my code looks like.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client({intents: [Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds]});

// yada yada variables

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
   console.log('Doing Stuff')
}
```

I tried surrounding it with console.log(). Anything outside fired, anything inside didn't.
No errors pop up, but testing my code results in nothing.

I'm fairly new to Javascript and Discord.js, so I don't know what else I should try.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73369912/15353979

Comment: No, as you can see, I already have messageCreate and not just message

Comment: What about the intents?

Comment: @AliNavidi You can see that both `Guilds` and `GuildMessages` intents are present. That's enough and `messageCreate` should fire.

Comment: @Sman is your bot logged in?

Comment: @Sman please check on developers portal that if you have enabled intents or not.

Comment: What are you trying to get `message` from DM or `guildMessage`. Do you have enable that feature at developer portal

Comment: Yes, my bot is logged in @ZsoltMeszaros.

Comment: Okay, so, it turns out, my bot was logged in, but it was logged in at the wrong place [essentially the last line of code]. My bad.