# I am trying do deploy discord bot in javascript on replit but its just replying only when i mention bot instead of any normal message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, replit

I have developed a discord bot in python but getting problems in javascript one.

I have tried a few solutions from StackOverflow itself but I can't figure out how to make it work. And much confusion due to solutions available online about discord bot and whenever you try to deploy it as it shows many version/deprecation errors of nodejs and discord.

Problem is that my bot code as follows replying only when I mention them but I want it to reply on any message like for example I take `"boomer"` as my message but the bot doesn't respond to it at all.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { Client } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    32509
  ]
})
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setActivity('Running a test, hopefully.');
})

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("boomer")) {
    message.channel.send("how are you there!");
  }

  if (message.author.bot) return false;

  if (message.content.includes("@here") || message.content.includes("@everyone") || message.type == "REPLY") return false;

  if (message.mentions.has(client.user.id)) {
    message.channel.send("Hello there!");
  }

});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: well I am commenting late after getting answer but in future if anyone faces any issue for him the version of discord.js was 14.2.0 
Thank you again for resolving query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current intent `32509` the following ones are enabled:

- `GUILDS` (1 << 0)
- `GUILD_BANS` (1 << 2)
- `GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS` (1 << 3)
- `GUILD_INTEGRATIONS` (1 << 4)
- `GUILD_WEBHOOKS` (1 << 5)
- `GUILD_INVITES` (1 << 6)
- `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` (1 << 7)
- `GUILD_MESSAGES` (1 << 9)
- `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` (1 << 10)
- `GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING` (1 << 11)
- `DIRECT_MESSAGES` (1 << 12)
- `DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` (1 << 13)
- `DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING` (1 << 14)

The problem is you've added lots of unnecessary ones but missing the `MESSAGE_CONTENT` intent. It means [`message.content` doesn't have any value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73037243/6126373), but `message.mentions` has. That's why it works when you mention the bot and doesn't work when you check if the `message.content` includes the string `"boomer"`.

To solve this, you can add 32768 (`1 << 15`) to the current number:

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [65277],
});
```

or even better, just use the ones you actually need:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
});
```