# updated discord.js to version 14.6.0

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

and I've just updated to ver 14.6.0 of discord.js and non of my cmds are working why is that my code always worked before hand? example of my code here ->

```
    if (message.content.startsWith('L!poke')) {
        let targetMember = message.mentions.members.first();
        if (!targetMember) return message.reply('you need to tag a user in order to poke them!!'); 
        // message goes below!
        const num = (Math.floor(Math.random()* 6)+1).toString();
        message.channel.send({files: [`./poke/poke${num}.gif`]})
        //message.channel.send({files:["./nom/"]})
        message.channel.send(` ${targetMember.user},your you getting poked!!! -_-`);
        //let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        //embed.setImage('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/541152846540701706/653867448553963550/fm49srQ.gif')
        //message.channel.send(embed);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [message.content doesn't have any value in Discord.js v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036854/message-content-doesnt-have-any-value-in-discord-js-v14)

Answer (score 1):

You need additional intent flag in order to read content of the messages.

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    // This will give you events about messages
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,

    // And this is flag you're probably missing:
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ]
});
```

Also, don't forget that this intent should be enabled on Discord Developers Portal for your bot.