# Discord.js not getting message content

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to get the message content of the messages sent in my server and the bot only returns a blank character. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Code

```
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  console.log(message.content)
});
```

Message

[image]

Console print

[image]

Comment: Where's your message.content string? You don't provide any string to make it as message. So it will literally going to be an empty strings (*invisible character*)

Comment: Could this be a possible side affect from your client missing the message content intent? Make sure to enable the intent through your developer portal and include the bit in your client intents

Comment: Make sure you have message content intents enabled on your discord developers portal dashboard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [message.content doesn't have any value in Discord.js v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036854/message-content-doesnt-have-any-value-in-discord-js-v14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think you forgot to include the new `MessageContent` Intent.
You have to add it to the `intents` array on your `Client` instance like I have on mine:

[image: my discord bot intents]

Comment: Probably the answer, thanks for your help. After a little while it just started working (don't know why). Thanks for trying to help though!

Answer (score -1):

Get your string on your discord server such as `args[0]` to get this method you can use `const args` first then use your `message.content`

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async(message) => {
    const args = message.content.slice().trim().split(/\s+/);
    console.log(args[0]);
});
```

[image: Sample given]

You can also adjust it to get all of the word they say:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async(message) => {
    const args = message.content.slice().trim().split(/\s+/);
    console.log(args.splice(0).join(" "));
});
```

[image: Sample Given2]

Comment: If `message.content` is returning `""` how is slice, trim, and split supposed to affect it?

Comment: I'm also confused on what your answer is trying to solve. The OP is getting a blank response from `message.content`, which is the entire message string. Why are you splitting a string and getting the first index?

Comment: He can also remove it since I only copied it in to my prefix workout, Its not actually going to affect the `splice`

Comment: He wanted to get the message thru discord, ofcourse I provided how he will going to get that string sing splice(0) to get all the words

Comment: `message.content` *is the string* there's no need to manipulate the string and turn it into an array

Comment: Then why it got empty string?

Comment: Because of `intents`? then why its working if its because the intents?

Comment: [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) will not magically give an empty string content. Creating args is a very DJS specific thing.

Comment: As I mentioned, OP can  remove those 3, the main point here is to use *splice(0)* to replace the `invisible character` into the main `string given`

Comment: I have all intents enabled through the dev panel and have my intents set to 32767 (enable all intents) - still isn't working