# Discord bot responds to DMs only, not to commands in guilds

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm programming my first bot for discord by javascript and with discord.js v14. My bot simply obeys the command in private chat, it doesn't send a message back if it's through a server. Can someone help me?
My code:

```js
//npm é um gerenciador de pacotes

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');
const { Guilds, GuildMembers, DirectMessages } = GatewayIntentBits;
const { Channel, GuildMember, Message, User, Reaction } = Partials;
const client = new Client({
  intents: [Guilds, GuildMembers, DirectMessages],
  partials: [Channel, GuildMember, Message, User, Reaction],
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(
    `Bot foi iniciado, com ${client.users.cache.size} usuários, em ${client.channels.cache.size} canais, em      ${client.guilds.cache.size} servidores.`,
  );
  client.user.setActivity(
    `Eu estou em ${client.guilds.cache.size} servidores.`,
  ); //atualiza status do bot
});

client.on('guildCreate', (guild) => {
  console.log(
    `O bot entrou nos servidores: ${guild.cache.name} (id: ${guild.cache.id}). População: ${guild.cache.memberCount} membros.`,
  );
  client.user.setActivity(`Estou em ${client.guilds.cache.size} servidores!`);
}); //toda vez q o bot entra num server, esse comando é executado e atualiza o status do bot

client.on('guildDelete', (guild) => {
  console.log(
    `O bot foi removido do servidor: ${guild.cache.name} (id: ${guild.cache.id}).); client.user.setActivity(Serving ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers!`,
  );
}); //avisa caso o bot seja excluido de um servidor

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  let prefix = config.prefix; //liga o prefixo do arquivo config para comando

  if (message.author.bot) return; //nao responda outros bots
  if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
  //if(message.channel.type === "dm") return; //nao responda por DM

  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g); //liga o prefix do config para comando
  const comando = args.shift().toLowerCase(); //parametros do comando

  if (comando === 'ping') {
    //define o comando depois do prefixo digitado pelo usuario
    const m = await message.channel.send('Ping?'); //mensagem
    m.edit(
      `:ping_pong: Pong! A latencia é ${
        m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp
      } ms. A latencia da API é ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)} ms`,
    ); //edita a propria mensagem 'm'
  }
}); //evento de mensagem do bot

client.login(config.token); //liga o bot
```

I tried to reinstall discord.js, I also installed an older version, but apparently the problem is not in the library because it works, but only in private chat.

Comment: Please check your formatting and put codeblocks within `blocks` rather than `inline` code. [See here for how](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 1):

It's because without the `MessageContent` intent you only receive the `message.content` in DMs but not in guilds. It will be [an empty string in guilds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73037243/6126373).

You will need to add `MessageContent` to your intent array:

```js
const { Guilds, GuildMembers, DirectMessages, MessageContent } =
  GatewayIntentBits;
const { Channel, GuildMember, Message, User, Reaction } = Partials;
const client = new Client({
  intents: [Guilds, GuildMembers, DirectMessages, MessageContent],
  partials: [Channel, GuildMember, Message, User, Reaction],
});
```