# My discord bot(js) is online but not responding i guess it's with intents i cant fix it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

`const express = require("express")`
`const app = express()`
`const fs = require('fs')`
`const dotenv = require("dotenv")` dotenv.config() app.get("/",(req,res) => {  res.send("hello hell!") })`

`app.listen(3000, () => {`
`console.log("project is ready!")`
`})`

`let Discord = require("discord.js")`
`client = new Discord.Client({intents: 32767})`

`client.on("ready", () => {`
 `console.log(`logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)`
[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUWCG.png)
I tried changing the Intents but still its not working,Im a newbie i guess there are some mistakes in my explainings sorry!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord bot doesn't answer commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75525777/discord-bot-doesnt-answer-commands)

Answer (score 0):

To use messages's content, you need to go to your discord developer portal and enable message content underneath of the bot section.

If that is already enabled, you need to use intents GuildMessages and MessageContent, as for the partials you also need Message. I recommend you to use a command handler though, because it makes code easier to read. If you need help to set it up DM me on Discord (Kama#3746)