# Discord bot doesn't execute commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a bot that plays music, can ban and kick people, and shows the number of members and online numbers on the server.

I tried my best but it didn't write anything even when I wrote `"hi"` to test it.

Can you help me with this?

```
const { Discord ,Client, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { createAudioResource, createAudioPlayer, joinVoiceChannel, StreamType, AudioPlayerStatus } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core-discord');
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
const client = new Client({ intents: [32509] });
require('dotenv').config();
const { TOKEN, ID, SECRET } = process.env;

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: ID,
  clientSecret: SECRET,
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'hi') {
    msg.reply('hi, how are you?');
  }
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.guild) return;
  
    if (message.content.startsWith('!kick')) {
      const user = message.mentions.users.first();
      if (user) {
        const member = message.guild.member(user);
        if (member) {
          member.kick('Information is in logs').then(() => {
            message.reply(`${user.tag} kicked`);
          }).catch(err => {
            message.reply('Kick was not successful!');
            console.error(err);
          });
        } else {
          message.reply("User is not in this server");
        }
      } else {
        message.reply("You must specify a user to kick");
      }
    }
  
    if (message.content.startsWith('!ban')) {
      const user = message.mentions.users.first();
      if (user) {
        const member = message.guild.member(user);
        if (member) {
          member.ban({
            reason: 'Information is in logs',
          }).then(() => {
            message.reply(`${user.tag} banned`);
          }).catch(err => {
            message.reply('Ban was not successful!');
            console.error(err);
          });
        } else {
          message.reply("User is not in this server");
        }
      } else {
        message.reply("You must specify a user to ban");
      }
    }
  });

  client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith('!')) return;
  
    const args = message.content.slice(1).trim().split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
    if (command === 'play') {
      if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
        message.reply('Please join a voice chat');
        return;
      }
  
      const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
        guildId: message.guild.id,
        adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
      });
  
      const link = args[0];
      if (!link) {
        message.reply('Please enter a YouTube or Spotify link.');
        return;
      }
  
      if (!link.includes('youtube.com') && !link.includes('youtu.be') && !link.includes('spotify.com')) {
        message.reply('Please enter a valid YouTube or Spotify link.');
        return;
      }
  
      try {
        if (link.includes('spotify.com')) {
          const id = link.split('/').pop().split('?')[0];
          const data = await spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant();
          const token = data.body['access_token'];
          spotifyApi.setAccessToken(token);
          const track = await spotifyApi.getTrack(id);
          const stream = await ytdl(track.body.preview_url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
          const resource = createAudioResource(stream, { inputType: StreamType.Opus });
          const player = createAudioPlayer();
          connection.subscribe(player);
          player.play(resource);
          player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
            connection.destroy();
          });
          message.reply(`The song called \`${track.body.name}\` is playing...`);
        } else if (link.includes('youtube.com') || link.includes('youtu.be')) {
          const stream = await ytdl(link, { filter: 'audioonly' });
          const resource = createAudioResource(stream, { inputType: StreamType.Opus });
          const player = createAudioPlayer();
          connection.subscribe(player);
          player.play(resource);
          player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
            connection.destroy();
          });
          const info = await ytdl.getBasicInfo(link);
          message.reply(`The video called\`${info.videoDetails.title}\` is playing...`);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('An error occured.');
      }
    }
  });

  client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldState, newState) => {
    if (!oldState.channel && newState.channel) {
      const guild = newState.guild;
      const voiceChannel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name.includes('Members: '));
      if (voiceChannel) {
        const memberCount = guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
        const onlineCount = guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot && member.presence?.status === 'online').size;
        voiceChannel.setName(`Members: ${memberCount} (${onlineCount} online)`);
      }
    }
  });

client.login(TOKEN);
```

When I tried to log in as bot there is no problem. it says its logged in.

But when i try any of these commands bot doesn't do anything.

Even I get no errors in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current intent `32509` the following ones are enabled:

- `GUILDS` (1 << 0)
- `GUILD_BANS` (1 << 2)
- `GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS` (1 << 3)
- `GUILD_INTEGRATIONS` (1 << 4)
- `GUILD_WEBHOOKS` (1 << 5)
- `GUILD_INVITES` (1 << 6)
- `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` (1 << 7)
- `GUILD_MESSAGES` (1 << 9)
- `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` (1 << 10)
- `GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING` (1 << 11)
- `DIRECT_MESSAGES` (1 << 12)
- `DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` (1 << 13)
- `DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING` (1 << 14)

The problem is you've added unnecessary ones but missing the `MESSAGE_CONTENT` intent. It means [`message.content` doesn't have any value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73037243/6126373). Also, make sure you enable the necessary intents on the developer portal (see the linked answer).

To solve this, you can add 32768 (`1 << 15`) to the current number:

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [65277],
});
```

You should also replace `client.on('message'` with `client.on('messageCreate'` and make sure you only have one event listener.