# GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent is empty in discord.js v14.11.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

In a similar way to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036854/message-content-doesnt-have-any-value-in-discord-js), the intent `GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent` doesn't seem to have a value.

The Privileged Gateway Intents is activated in the Developper portal
[Image of my Privileged Gateway Intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eisAt.png)

I added the `GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent` to my intents

```
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildInvites,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildEmojisAndStickers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildIntegrations,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildWebhooks,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    ],
});
```

and i get this error on startup

```
    throw new DiscordjsRangeError(ErrorCodes.BitFieldInvalid, bit);
    ^

RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined.
    at IntentsBitField.resolve (/home/pascalaubistrot/dev/Discord-Log/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:172:11)
    at /home/pascalaubistrot/dev/Discord-Log/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:167:54
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at IntentsBitField.resolve (/home/pascalaubistrot/dev/Discord-Log/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:167:40)
    at new BitField (/home/pascalaubistrot/dev/Discord-Log/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:33:38)
    at new IntentsBitField (/home/pascalaubistrot/dev/Discord-Log/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/IntentsBitField.js:9:1)
    at Client._validateOptions (/home/pascalaubistrot/dev/Discord-Log/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:494:25)
    at new Client (/home/pascalaubistrot/dev/Discord-Log/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:78:10)    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pascalaubistrot/dev/Discord-Log/index.js:8:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14) {
  code: 'BitFieldInvalid'
}
```

and VScode doesn't recognise the MessageContent flag
[Image of VScode intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xmua.png)
and when I print the value of the intents it is undefined

```
GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers : 2
GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent : undefined
```

And here is a console.log of the GateWayIntentsBits

```
{
  '1': 'Guilds',
  '2': 'GuildMembers',
  '4': 'GuildBans',
  '8': 'GuildEmojisAndStickers',
  '16': 'GuildIntegrations',
  '32': 'GuildWebhooks',
  '64': 'GuildInvites',
  '128': 'GuildVoiceStates',
  '256': 'GuildPresences',
  '512': 'GuildMessages',
  '1024': 'GuildMessageReactions',
  '2048': 'GuildMessageTyping',
  '4096': 'DirectMessages',
  '8192': 'DirectMessageReactions',
  '16384': 'DirectMessageTyping',
  '65536': 'GuildScheduledEvents',
  '1048576': 'AutoModerationConfiguration',
  '2097152': 'AutoModerationExecution',
  Guilds: 1,
  GuildMembers: 2,
  GuildModeration: 4,
  GuildBans: 4,
  GuildEmojisAndStickers: 8,
  GuildIntegrations: 16,
  GuildWebhooks: 32,
  GuildInvites: 64,
  GuildVoiceStates: 128,
  GuildPresences: 256,
  GuildMessages: 512,
  GuildMessageReactions: 1024,
  GuildMessageTyping: 2048,
  DirectMessages: 4096,
  DirectMessageReactions: 8192,
  DirectMessageTyping: 16384,
  GuildScheduledEvents: 65536,
  AutoModerationConfiguration: 1048576,
  AutoModerationExecution: 2097152
}
```

Version of discord.js: `version: '14.11.0`

Version of discord API: `APIVersion: '10`

Edit:
I found out that i can pass the bitfields directly and the bot work fine and i can read the content of the message

```
const client = new Client({
    intents: 101917
});
```

I didn't find anyone else having this problem apart from this [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036854/message-content-doesnt-have-any-value-in-discord-js) which was resolved but the solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you post the value of `GatewayIntentBits`? (i.e add `console.log(GatewayIntentBits)` somewhere)

Comment: Here you go I added it in my post @ZsoltMeszaros

Comment: Thank you, could you also check your discord.js and API version? You can `import { APIVersion, version } from 'discord.js'` and then just `console.log({ APIVersion, version })`

Comment: `{ APIVersion: '10', version: '14.11.0' }` 

I also made progress on my own, i passed the bitfield directly `intents: 101917` and I can access the message content. So i think the problem come from my installation of discord.js. But i just did `npm i discord.js` and changed version to try resolved the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using discord.js v13. It uses Discord's API v9, which doesn't have the `GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent` intent.

You can verify that here [discord-api-types v9 GatewayIntentBits reference](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v9/enum/GatewayIntentBits)

The MessageContent intent was introduced in Discord's API v10, so you should upgrade to discord.js v14 which uses the newer API v10 and that should fix the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm on API v10, and on discord.js v14.11.0