# Trying to make a discord message logger for v14 but i cant get it working

Tags: discord.js

idk what is wrong but there are no errors nor is it send to the channel. any help would be great

```
  client.on('message', async message => {
    const channelName = "logs";
    // Create an embed.
    const msglogEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle('Message Log')
      .setDescription(`${message.author.tag}: ${message.content}`)
      .setTimestamp(message.createdAt);
  
    // Get the channel by name.
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelName);
  
    // Send the embed to the specified channel.
    await channel.send({ embeds: [msglogEmbed] });
  
    // Console log the message.
    console.log(`Message logged to channel ${channelName}`);
  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [message.content doesn't have any value in Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036854/message-content-doesnt-have-any-value-in-discord-js)

Comment: Try using channel id and Channel.get instead and make sure you have the needed intents

Answer (score -1):

You cannot get channels by their names. You need to use their channel IDs.

```js
const channelId = "1122334455667788";

// Get the channel by ID.
const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);
```

Alternatively, you can search for a channel by its name.

```js
const channelName = "logs";

// Get the channel by Name.
const channel = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === channelName).first();
```