# Discord.js bot not responding when command is typed

Tags: discord.js

My discord.js bot isn't responding to commands. However, it is online.

My code is provided below:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const prefix = '!';
const client = new Discord.Client({
    allowedMentions: {
        parse: [`users`, `roles`],
        repliedUser: true,

    },
    intents: [
        "Guilds",
        "GuildMessages",
        "GuildPresences",
        "GuildMembers",
        "GuildMessageReactions",
    ],

});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
});

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    // Test command
    if (command === 'test') {
        message.channel.send('The Bot is currently working properly!');
    }


});

client.login("my discord token")
```

I tried the command `!test` and the bot, according to the code, should be responding "The Bot is currently working properly!". However, there's no response.

I changed the code from

```js
if (message === 'test') {
        message.channel.send('The Bot is currently working properly!');
}
```

to

```js
if (command === 'test') {
        message.channel.send('The Bot is currently working properly!');
}
```

and that din't do anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [message.content doesn't have any value in Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036854/message-content-doesnt-have-any-value-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 0):

add  "MessageContent" intent it should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### MessageContent Intent

[image: discord dev portal]

Make sure the above intent is enabled on your [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

Also provide `"MessageContent"` in your bot intents:

```js
intents: [
    "Guilds",
    "GuildMessages",
    "GuildPresences",
    "GuildMembers",
    "GuildMessageReactions",
    "MessageContent"
]
```