# Discord.js reads Intents as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My simple test code

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const { MessageEmbed, channels } = require('discord.js');

client.login('no peeking');

client.on('ready', readyUser);

function readyUser(){
    console.log('Bot is ready and logged in');
}

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    const prefix = "!";
    const args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (message.author.id != client.user.id) {
    }
});
```

gives error

> `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')`
> regarding line 2.

From what I found, this could be caused by my intents being disabled in Discord developer portal. Even though I enabled them and the problem is still in place.

[What I found (enabled intents)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFRuv.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In discord.js v14, you need to use `GatewayIntentBits` when declaring the intents in the client. An example would be something like this:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        // ...
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using v14 of discord.js, `Intents` are no longer available.

You'll need to use [`GatewayIntentBits`](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/GatewayIntentBits) instead:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
  ]
});
```