# discord.js Property 'messages' does not exist on type 'TextChannel'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord.js

Today I switched from JS to TS (mainly because of its type annotation) and when trying to save a channel to a variable, I got the following error: `Property 'messages' does not exist on type 'TextChannel'` (got the error when trying to access the `messages` property somewhere in the code). The [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/TextChannel) show that messages is a valid property of TextChannel, so what's going on here?

The code I'm using to get the channel is `channel = guild.channels.cache.get(id)` and I added `as TextChannel` to the end (and declaring the variable likes this: `let channel: TextChannel`). I also tried `BaseGuildTextChannel` but got the same results.

I also tried logging the type of the `channel` variable with `console.log(typeof channel)` but it just returned `object`

reproducible example as requested

```
import {Client, TextChannel} from 'discord.js'
const client = new Client({intents: []})

client.once("ready",()=>{
    client.channels.fetch("id of a text channel").then((chan:TextChannel)=>{
        if (!chan.isTextBased()) return //TS2339
        chan.messages.fetch().then(()=>{ //TS2339
            console.log("fetched messages")
        })
    })
})

client.login("token")
```

Comment: Type casting is kind of a hack but that error message is still weird. Anyway, could you please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros added a reproducible example.

Answer (score -2):

Using resolve will keep your code cleaner and allow you to visualise your code better than chaining `.then` statements.
Doing this and enabling [Message Intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73040824/discord-js-reads-intents-as-undefined) should fix your code.

```js
const guild = client.guilds.resolve('ID');
const channel = guild.channels.resolve('ID');

if(!channel.isTextBased()) return;

const messages = await channel.messages.fetch();
```

Comment: The reproducible example does not reflect the actual code. The problem is that the typescript transpiler throws an error because it thinks that `messages` is not a valid property of `TextChannel`