# Discordjs v14 TypeError: (intermediate value).setColor is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, typeerror

I am trying to create a command where it returns an embedded message when /ping command is typed and I am getting this error.

```
      .setColor("#FF0000")
       ^

TypeError: (intermediate value).setColor is not a function
    at Object.run (C:\Users\dhart\Desktop\Projects\ExistentialThreat\commands\Info\ping.js:9:8)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dhart\Desktop\Projects\ExistentialThreat\events\interactionCreate.js:24:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

My code is:

```
const { Embed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "ping",
  description: "Returns websocket latency",

  run: async (client, interaction) => {
    const embed = new Embed()
      .setColor("#FF0000")
      .setTitle(" Pong!")
      .setDescription(`Latency : ${client.ws.ping}ms`)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter({ text: `Requested by ${interaction.user.tag}`, iconURL: `${interaction.user.displayAvatarURL()}` });
    interaction.followUp({ embeds: [embed] });
  },
};
```

Idk how to fix this and I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In discord.js v14 `MessageEmbed` has been renamed to `EmbedBuilder`. As you're trying to import and use the [`Embed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Embed) class, you receive that error.

You'll need to require `EmbedBuilder` instead:

```js
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setColor("#FF0000")
  .setTitle(" Pong!")
  .setDescription(`Latency : ${client.ws.ping}ms`)
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter({
    text: `Requested by ${interaction.user.tag}`,
    iconURL: `${interaction.user.displayAvatarURL()}`,
  });

interaction.followUp({ embeds: [embed] });
```