# Discord.js: Invalid bitfield flag or number: GUILDS?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AhY5.png)

i am trying to create my own discord bot and it gives me that error I don't know what to do
it's giving me that error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G6xY.png)

can you help me, please?

my version of discord.js is 14.0.3
and my node.js version is 18.5.0

I tried everything that I could even your tips and I can't do this so do you have any tips to please help me because I promised a friend I would help him

I GOTTA SAY THAT ITS THE FIRST TIME THAT IT HAPPENED TO ME AND BEFORE THAT I CREATED 2 BOTS

Comment: to check your discord.js version go to package.json, and check the part where it's `"discord.js" : "v......"`, the v... is your version of discord.js. Also please put your code directly as text instead of an image. So edit your message now to include everything I just said

Comment: but how can you help me with the error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)

Answer (score 1):

In `discord.js` v14, `Intents` have been replaced by `GatewayIntentBits`. Therefore, the correct way for creating the client is like this:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        // ...
    ]
})
```

For more information, you can go here => [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)

Comment: but now it sais "GatewayIntentBits is not defined"

Comment: You haven't imported `GatewayIntentBits` from `discord.js` at the top which is why the error is coming. Add this line to the top => `const { GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js')`

Answer (score 0):

They changed how this works in discord.js v14.
Example from [the official updating guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#enum-values):

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js'); // old
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js'); // new

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS], partials: ['CHANNEL'] }); // old
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds], partials: [Partials.Channel] }); // new
```

Comment: but now it sais "GatewayIntentBits is not defined"

Comment: Have you imported the "GatewayIntentBits" object from discord.js like in this example?

Answer (score -1):

This error will happen if intents are missing or not properly listed. Refer to the code here and it will work.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new.Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        "GUILDS",
         "GUILD_MESSAGES"
        ]
});
```

Comment: It's incorrect. You basically copied the original code that caused the error.

Comment: no error showed up

Comment: Because you're using an older version of discord.js

Comment: oh now its not working

Comment: I know, lots of things won't work in v14: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14

Comment: yeah... its true