# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS') when trying to do 'node index.js'

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a discord bot using the OPENAI API and when I try to use the command 'node index' I get the following error:

[ERROR IMAGE][1]

index.js FILE:

```
const {
    Client,
    Intents,
} = require('discord.js');

const bot = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.Guild, Intents.FLAGS.Guild_Members, Intents.FLAGS.Guild_Messages]
});

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Bot ${bot.user.tag} is logged in!`);
});

bot.login('OTk5MTQ0NjU3ODgxNjc3ODY1.GvMgQX.dz3r43fDHi6nqB_cO55gSHhO2jJJ-zBKQIjF5k');

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Bot ${bot.user.tag} is logged in!`);
  });
```

Package.json file:

```
{
   "name": "discord-gpt3-bot",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/nrrpatel/discordbot.git"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/nrrpatel/discordbot/issues"
      },
      "homepage": "https://github.com/nrrpatel/discordbot#readme",
      "dependencies": {
        "discord.js": "^14.0.3",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
        "openai-api": "^1.3.1",
        "typescript": "^4.7.4"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using an older implementation for the newest version of `discord.js`. If you follow the [changelog for its v14](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#common-client-initialization-changes), you'll see the client initialization changed.

So instead of:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
```

You should be using:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });
```

Comment: thank you for your answer as I was able to reslove it using your answer