# Module '"discord.js"' has no exported member 'Intents'

Tags: typescript, module, discord, discord.js, bots

Module '"discord.js"' has no exported member 'Intents'.

My code is:

````
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

const bot = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE
    ]
});

bot.on('ready', ()=>{
    console.log("ready")
})

bot.login(process.env.TOKEN)```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)

Answer (score 1):

Use IntentsBitField instead

````
    import DiscordJS, { IntentsBitField } from 'discord.js'
    import dotenv from 'dotenv';

const bot = new Client({
    intents: [
    IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages
]    });

bot.on('ready', ()=>{
    console.log("ready")
})

bot.login(process.env.TOKEN)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should use GatewayIntentBits now.

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits } from 'discord.js';

const bot = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Flags.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.Flags.GuildMessages
]
});

bot.on('ready', ()=>{
    console.log("ready")
})

bot.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```