# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS') discord.js

Tags: discord

so this is my bot code

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log('Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!')
  console.log("Bot is online!")
})

client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "ping") {
    msg.reply("no1se");
  }
})

client.login("my token")
```

The error i get is this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/no1seAlerts-1/index.js:4:47)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
Hint: hit control+c anytime to enter REPL.
(node:2004) ExperimentalWarning: stream/web is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

yea so im trying to make a discor dbot everytime when i try to run it and make it online i get this error code i have no idea what to do and i would really appreciate any help thank you!

Comment: Maybe is it because you forgot to put `;` in end of first line? Or maybe you are using older version of discord.js whi doesn't have flags in it?

Comment: What is the version of `discord.js` in your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using discord.js v13, you can try and change your `client` to:

```
const client = new Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `Intents` with `IntentsBitField`

In your example it would be:

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages] });
```

This was changed with version 14 of discord.js I believe.

Alternatively you can use GatewayIntentBits:

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages] });
```

More information [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents)

Hope this helps!