# Discord.js select menu interaction failed after selecting an option

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a select menu where once a menu item is selected, it should send an embed with some info but it doesn't, only *"This interaction failed"* is displayed. There is no error in the console.

Here is my code:

```js
if (!args[0]) {
  const home = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setAuthor({
      name: `Welcome to the help panel.`,
      iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 512 }),
    })
    .setColor(COLORS)
    .setDescription(
      `You can start streaming music straight away without any setup, just run the \`${PREFIX}play\` command, give it something to search for and you're good to go! \n\nUnlock exclusive benefits by purchasing a premium membership: **[Buy Premium](https://www.patreon.com/join/EliMusic)** \n\n**All Link:** [WebSite](https://elimusic.top/) | [Vote](https://top.gg/bot/944606401219690516/vote) | [Support](https://discord.gg/Q4RWKU2UqB)`,
    )
    .setFooter({
      text: `© MihaiT`,
      iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL(),
    });

  const info = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor(COLORS)
    .setAuthor({
      name: `Eli's Commands`,
      iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 512 }),
    })
    .addFields(
      {
        name: `<:Eli_Bot:972786663078105128> Info`,
        value: `Detailed help for an order: \`${PREFIX}help [commands]\` \nFor more help, visit our [support server](https://discord.gg/Q4RWKU2UqB)`,
      },
      {
        name: `<:Eli_ADD:972784975172751380> Comandos`,
        value: `\`${PREFIX}about\`: Stats and bots details. \n\`${PREFIX}help\`: Help commands. \n\`${PREFIX}invite\`: You receive a link so you can invite me to any server you manage. \n\`${PREFIX}vote\`: Vote for Nakano on Top.gg \n\`${PREFIX}support\`: To join communities.`,
      },
    )
    .setFooter({
      text: `© MihaiT`,
      iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL(),
    });

  const components = (state) => [
    new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
      new SelectMenuBuilder()
        .setCustomId('help-menu')
        .setPlaceholder('Please Select a Category')
        .setDisabled(state)
        .addOptions([
          {
            label: `Home`,
            value: `home`,
            description: `Go home`,
            emoji: `<:EliOfficial:972798080393052191>`,
          },
          {
            label: `Info`,
            value: `info`,
            description: `See info commands`,
            emoji: `<:Eli_Bot:972786663078105128>`,
          },
        ]),
    ),
  ];

  message.reply({
    embeds: [home],
    allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false },
    components: components(true),
  });

  const filter = (interaction) => interaction.user.id === message.author.id;

  const collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
    filter,
    componentType: 'SELECT_MENU',
    max: 10,
  });

  collector.on('collect', (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.values[0] === 'home') {
      interaction.reply({ embeds: [home], ephemeral: true });
    } else if (interaction.values[0] === 'info') {
      interaction.reply({ embeds: [info], ephemeral: true });
    }
  });
}
```

If you look at the image below, you will see that it doesn't give me anything after I select an option. I use discord.js v14.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `createMessageComponentCollector`'s `componentType` option should be an enum. You should use [`ComponentType.SelectMenu`](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/ComponentType) and it will work:

```js
const collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
  filter,
  componentType: ComponentType.SelectMenu,
  max: 10,
});
```

[image]

Related answer: [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73028855/6126373)