# Why doesn't my discord bot get online when I type node main.js in command promp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This is my `package.json` file:

```js
{
  "name": "bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My  discord Bot",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Undefined Human",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^14.3.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the `main.js` file:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
    ]
});



client.once('ready', () => { 
    console.log('GhxstedCloudz is online');
});




client.login('my bot token');
```

and here is the error I get when I type `node .` or `node main.js` in the terminal:

```js
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\bot\main.js:5
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\bot\main.js:5:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)

Answer (score 0):

There is no more `Discord.Intents.FLAGS` thing
Now typings are different and in v14 we need to use this

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
       GatewayIntentBits.Guilds //etc.
    ])
```

Everything you need to know is [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#before-you-start)