# Problem with discord bot Node.js TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')

Tags: node.js, discord

hi i dont know anything of coding, but i have tried to make a discord bot with a tutorial but on vs code i get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')

and this are the first 14 line of the code

```
require('dotenv').config();

const {REST} = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { Client, Intents, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const { Player } = require("discord-player")

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES]
});
```

if someone know what i can do it would be appreciated.

Comment: `Intents` is `undefined`

Comment: and what i have to do

Comment: Please try reading the how to upgrade page in https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#before-you-start

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)

Answer (score 0):

`Intents` is now `GatewayIntentBits` as of v14

https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#enum-values

https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/GatewayIntentBits

Comment: i've tried with GatewayIntentBits and it shows this error 


TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'GUILDS')


on this lines of code, idk how to put the GatewayIntentBits.


const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


const client = new Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.FLAGS.GUILDS, GatewayIntentBits.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, GatewayIntentBits.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES]
});

Comment: You don't need `FLAGS` anymore, the properties are directly on the `GatewayIntentBits` object. The properties have also been renamed slightly, refer to the links above to find the new names.