# TypeError: interaction.isCommand is not a function Discord js error (v14)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm having this problem related to my handler. Every time I do a command this error appears. I send handler and example command code (They all follow the same style)

```
//Module export
const fs = require("fs-extra")
client.commands = new Discord.Collection()

const commandsFolder = fs.readdirSync("./commands");
for (const folder of commandsFolder) {
    const commandsFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
    for (const file of commandsFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
}

client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
  if(!interaction.isCommand()) return;
  
    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName)
    if (!command) return

    command.execute(interaction)
})
```

And

```
const { ApplicationCommandOptionType, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    name: "avatar",
    data: {
        name: "avatar",
        description: "L'avatar dell'utente da te richiesto!",
        options: [
            {
                name: "user",
                description: "L'utente da cui prendere l'avatar",
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.User,
                required: true
            }
        ]

    },
    execute(interaction) {
        const Target = interaction.options.getUser('user');

        const Response = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor('#ffef00')
            .setAuthor({name: `Avatar di ${Target.tag}`})
            .setImage(Target.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
            .setFooter({ text: "Vedi di usarlo bene ;D"})

        
        interaction.reply({embeds: [Response]})
    }
}
```

And the entire error is:

```
TypeError: interaction.isCommand is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Utente\OneDrive\Desktop\Sooca\index.js:105:19)
    at Client.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Utente\OneDrive\Desktop\Sooca\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:81:12)
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\Utente\OneDrive\Desktop\Sooca\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Utente\OneDrive\Desktop\Sooca\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:352:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Utente\OneDrive\Desktop\Sooca\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:481:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Utente\OneDrive\Desktop\Sooca\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:321:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Utente\OneDrive\Desktop\Sooca\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\Utente\OneDrive\Desktop\Sooca\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1178:20)

Node.js v18.9.0
```

I tried to add

```
client.on("ready", () => {
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
        client.commands.forEach(command => {
            guild.commands.create(command.data)
        })
    })
})
```

But i gives that error:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'default_member_permissions' in undefined
    at GuildApplicationCommandManager.transformCommand (C:\Users\Utente\OneDrive\Desktop\Sooca\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:238:38)
    at GuildApplicationCommandManager.create (C:\Users\Utente\OneDrive\Desktop\Sooca\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:145:30)
    at C:\Users\Utente\OneDrive\Desktop\Sooca\index.js:107:28
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Utente\OneDrive\Desktop\Sooca\index.js:106:25
    at Collection.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Utente\OneDrive\Desktop\Sooca\index.js:105:25)
    at Client.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (C:\Users\Utente\OneDrive\Desktop\Sooca\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:385:17)
    at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (C:\Users\Utente\OneDrive\Desktop\Sooca\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:368:10)
```

It's so strange, i don't realy know why the code do this.
Can you help me?

Comment: Does this solve your question? [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)

Answer (score 0):

You're likely looking for [`interaction#isChatInputCommand()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/BaseInteraction?scrollTo=isChatInputCommand). Discord.js v14 changed a lot of methods and properties, so I recommend checking out [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14) as Caladan said in the comments.