# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'GUILD') on Node.js v18.12.1

Tags: discord.js

Here's my code:

```js
require('dotenv').config();

const {REST} = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { Client, Intents, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const { Player } = require("discord-player");

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const client = new Client [{
  intents: [
    Intents.GUILD,
    Intents.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.GUILD_VOICE_STATES
  ]
}];
```

I've been working this for an hour now but I still cant fix it

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)