# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'GUILDS')

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have looked over all over and I know there are similar threads here but I can't seam to figure it out. I have made a discord bot but it has problem with guilds and get the error in name.

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Collection, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js'); 
const { getVoiceConnection } = require("@discordjs/voice");

const client = new Client(clientSettingsObject());

client.deploySlash = {
  enabled: true,
  guild: false, 
}
client.config = require("./config/config.json");

client.commands = new Collection();
client.slashCommands = new Collection();
client.queues = new Collection();

require("./util/musicUtils.js")(client);

require("./util/handler.js")(client);

client.login(client.config.token);

function clientSettingsObject() {
  return {
    shards: "auto",
    allowedMentions: {
      parse: ["roles", "users", "everyone" ],
      repliedUser: false,
    },
    failIfNotExists: false,
    partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'],
    GatewayIntentBits: [ 
        GatewayIntentBits.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        GatewayIntentBits.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        GatewayIntentBits.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES
        ]
    }
}
```

I would expect it to work but have no clue, sorry for inconvenience but I am new to programing and is trying to learn, would be much appreciated

Comment: Does this solve your question => [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)

Comment: Don't need the `FLAGS` just `GatewayIntentBits.<X>....`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)