# Discord.js bot Intents Version 14.7.1

Tags: discord.js

I'm having an issue with importing the intents for my discord bot.
(It was working and I believe I updated my discord.js version, tried downgrading and still couldnt get it to work so now im trying to get the new intents to work.)

This is how I have intents

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.GUILDS,
    Intents.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
  ]
});
```

I get this error

```
    Intents.GUILDS,
            ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'GUILDS')
```

I have tried using different versions of discord.js and changing it from Intents to GatewayIntentBits like the discord.js docs says but then I get this error

```
      throw new DiscordjsTypeError(ErrorCodes.ClientMissingIntents);
      ^

TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
```

My original code was

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS"],
  allowedMentions: ["users"]
  });
```

and was working.

Does anyone know how to fix this or what version to downgrade for node and discord.js to get this working again.

Current Verions:
Discord.js: 14.7.1
Node: 19.3.0

**EDIT
I have updated my code to what discord.js refrences

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    ],
});
```

and am now receiving this error. Intents are also enabled in the bot.

```
throw new DiscordjsTypeError(ErrorCodes.ClientMissingIntents);
      ^

TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (/home/runner/Discord-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:489:13)
    at new Client (/home/runner/Discord-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:78:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Discord-Bot/member-count.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Discord-Bot/index.js:22:21) {
  code: 'ClientMissingIntents'
}

Node.js v19.3.0
exit status 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)

Answer (score 0):

`GatewayIntentBits` is the way to go as explained in the [guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents). Make sure to use PascalCase too.

The following error; `TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.` is because you either:

1. Have not enabled the intents necessary for the bot to perform its actions.
   Or 2. Have not enabled the correct [privileged intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents)

If this still doesn't work please include the full error stack and your code associated with that error.

There is no need to downgrade as V14(.7.1) is a stable and functional version.

###### A list of intents can be found [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents)

Comment: I have updated above to reference the guide, and got a new error. Any ideas? Intents are enabled in the discord bot panel

Comment: What is your new error?

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

I noticed you are using the `GatewayIntentBits` correctly, but you need to make sure that you have **enabled** the corresponding intents through the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers).

You can find the [Priveleged Gateway Intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lXct.png) switches at `https://discord.com/developers/applications/${APPLICATION_ID}/bot` and enable them all if you wish.

I also noticed that you are using replit. As far as I know, `Client._validateOptions` checks if your bot can use the specified intents.

### Example

It's always useful to add **partials**. I got this code from [this repo](https://github.com/intfract/discord/blob/main/index.js).

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials, Collection, ActivityType } = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
  ],
  partials: [Partials.Channel, Partials.Message, Partials.User, Partials.GuildMember, Partials.Reaction]
})
```

Answer (score -1):

hmm, have u tried putting the intents like

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents:['GuildMessageTyping','GuildMembers','GuildEmojisAndStickers']});
```

this seemed to work for me.

Answer (score -1):

In new version it works like this

```
 const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");

        const Intents = GatewayIntentBits;
        const allIntents = [
            Intents.Guilds,
            Intents.GuildMessages,
            Intents.GuildMembers,
            Intents.GuildPresences,
            Intents.GuildVoiceStates,
            Intents.GuildBans,
            Intents.GuildInvites,
            Intents.GuildWebhooks,
            Intents.GuildScheduledEvents,
            Intents.GuildMessageReactions,
            Intents.DirectMessages,
            Intents.DirectMessageTyping,
            Intents.DirectMessageReactions,
            Intents.GuildMessageTyping,
            Intents.MessageContent
        ]

        const client = new Client({
            intents: allIntents
        });
```

For more checkout [discordJsV14](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#before-you-start)