# I'm receiving the error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Guilds') what should I do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

For some reason, I'm getting the error shown below when running my bot.

```
                GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Guilds')
```

Previously I did not get this error and am unsure why it's doing this. Additionally, I've reviewed the other similar posts but they haven't resolved the issue.

Comment: What's your discord.js version? Where does `GatewayIntentBits` come from? Have you imported it?

Comment: My discord.js version is 12.5.3. When you say "imported", could you further elaborate on what you mean? I've added it to my index.js file if that's what you mean.

Comment: You should double check that you are actually running discord.js on the correct version, you can do so doing a couple of things, you can look at the package.json file and look for an entry that starts with discord.js and will look something like this

    **"discord.js": "^14.0.2"**,
You can also run npm list discord.js in your terminal and view the result there as well.

Comment: There is no `GatewayIntentBits` in discord.js v12, only available from v14. In v12, you can use `Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS` instead. But it's probably better to [upgrade to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14) now.

Comment: Just uploaded to v14, didn't realise I wasn't on the lastest version, tysm!