# Discord.js v14 Permissions | RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: STREAM

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I using discord.js V14 to check if a voice channel has streaming permissions enabled.

I tried this but it's not working.

```js
if (voiceChannel.permissionsFor(voiceChannel.guild.id).has("STREAM"))
```

It gives me the following error:

```
RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: STREAM.
```

btw, this code is working perfectly with the "Connect" permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v14, you can't use `STREAM` or other strings, you should use the enums from `PermissionFlagsBits`:

```js
const { PermissionFlagsBits } = require('discord.js')

// ...

if (voiceChannel.permissionsFor(voiceChannel.guild.id)
  .has(PermissionFlagsBits.Stream)
)
```

You can view all the available permissions here: [PermissionFlagsBits](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-payloads/common#PermissionFlagsBits)

Related: [Errors with enums in discord.js v14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73028855/6126373)

Answer (score 0):

Well, did you try using `Stream` instead of `STREAM` ? I can't see anything else if it's working using `Connect`.