# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD] });
```

> C:\Users\pulokgamer\Desktop\MUSIC BOT\index.js:2 const client = new
> Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]
> });
>
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)

Answer (score 0):

In discord.js v14 the previous v13 `Intents` class was updated to `IntentsBitField`. It operates pretty similarly just with a few different naming conventions.

Change:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD] });
```

To:

```
const { Client, IntentsBitField } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildVoiceStates, IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages, IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds] });
```

[IntentsBitField](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/14.9.0/class/IntentsBitField)
[GatewayIntentBits](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/GatewayIntentBits)