# Uncaught TypeError: MessageAttachment is not a constructor - How to fix?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am encountering an error in my JavaScript code that says "Uncaught TypeError: MessageAttachment is not a constructor". I am trying to use the MessageAttachment class to send an attachment in a message, but I am not sure what is causing this error. Here is the code snippet where I am trying to use MessageAttachment:

```
// Import required packages and modules
const { Client, MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const { GatewayIntentBits, IntentsBitField } = require('discord.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

//...

// Send the image to the Discord channel
if (imageUrl) {
  const attachment = new MessageAttachment(imageUrl, 'selfie.png');
  message.channel.send({ content: 'Here is your selfie!', files: [attachment] });
} else {
  message.channel.send('Error: Unable to generate the selfie. Please try again later.');
}
}
});
```

If you need more information i'd be happy to provide it.
Thank you for help in advance!

This is a part of the error message I recieved:

Uncaught TypeError TypeError: MessageAttachment is not a constructor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)

Answer (score 0):

`MessageAttachment` is v13 version on discord.js you need to chance it to `AttachmentBuilder` in v14 also u need to import it:

```
const { AttachmentBuilder } = require('discord.js');
```