# My code gives out an error what can i do?

Tags: discord, discord.js

Hi I just want to program a DC bot and I keep getting this error

```
/root/invite_tracker_bot/index.js:5
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/invite_tracker_bot/index.js:5:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1287:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v20.5.1
```

I've done npm install discord.js several times but it doesn't work nodejs is also the latest version I have no idea what the error is.

if you want to see the code say it

i Hope you can help me

btw. sorry for my bad English

i want to run the DC bot

the Code:

```js
const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');


const client = new Client({ 
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        // Add more intents here, if needed
        
    ] 
});




const prefix = '/'; // The prefix for bot commands


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});


client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return; // Prevent the bot from responding to its own messages
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return; // Ignore messages without prefix


    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


    if (command === 'setchannel') {
    // Check if the command was sent by an administrator
    if (!message.member.permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
        return message.reply('You do not have permission to execute this command.');
    }


    // Check if a channel was mentioned
    const mentionedChannel = message.mentions.channels.first();
    if (!mentionedChannel) {
        return message.reply('You must mention a channel to set it as an invitation link channel.');
    }


    // Save the mentioned channel in a database or a global variable
    // For example: botConfig.inviteChannel = mentionedChannel.id;
    // Note that you need to implement the database integration according to your needs


    message.reply(`The invitation link channel has been set to ${mentionedChannel}.`);
}



    if (command === 'getinvites') {
    // Get the invitations for the server
    const invites = await message.guild.fetchInvites();


    // Search for the desired invitation link
    const targetInvite = invites.find(invite => invite.url === 'YOUR_INLINK');


    if (!targetInvite) {
        return message.reply('The specified invitation link was not found.');
    }


    // Get the number of joined members via this link
    const joinedMembers = targetInvite.uses || 0;


    // Calculate the remaining time of the invitation
    const currentTime = new Date();
    const expirationTime = targetInvite.expiresAt || currentTime; // If the invitation does not expire
    const timeDifference = expirationTime - currentTime;
    const remainingTime = timeDifference > 0 ? timeDifference / 1000 : 0; // In seconds


    // Create an embed with the information
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Invitation Link Information')
        .setDescription(`Invitation link: ${targetInvite.url}\nNumber of joined: ${joinedMembers}\nTime remaining: ${remainingTime} Seconds`)
        .setColor('#3498db'); // sample color, you can customize it


    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
}


});


client.login('Here is my actual token');
```

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please edit your question to contain all the information (code) - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js v13 code breaks when upgrading to v14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028854/discord-js-v13-code-breaks-when-upgrading-to-v14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [discord.js documentation](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents), `Intents` seems to not exist but you can get `Flags.GuildPresences`, `Flags.GuildMembers` and `Flags.Guilds` from `IntentsBitField`.

You can find more about the `IntentsBitField` on the [documenation](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/14.11.0/class/IntentsBitField) or use the `GatewayIntentBits` wich allow you to directly get `Guilds` and `GuildMessages`. More on the GatewayIntentBits [here](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/GatewayIntentBits)

Comment: okay thx
i don´t know what to do

Comment: As said before, `Intents` does not exist in the discord.js API so you can either replace it with `IntentsBitField` or `GatewayIntentBits`.  `IntentsBitField` is a direct replacement and `GatewayIntentBits` seems to be a recent addition in discord.js but will need some code modification.

Comment: is that right?
'const { Client, BitField, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ 
    intents: [
        BitField.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        BitField.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
        
    ] 
});'

Comment: If it work I want to say yes but I don't know where you find `BitField` as I didn't mention it in my message.

Comment: thx i was stupid it works now

Comment: Oh, I undestand, you kept only the part after Intents. Glad I was able to help you. If this is the answer you needed, please mark it as so.